# How to select more then 1 item in listbox using selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
SelectElement Select = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlCUcardNo")));
Select.SelectByIndex(2);
```

I have a problem with listbox using selenium C#. I need to select more then one item(option in the list). Is there any possilitiy to select two items (second with ctrl) ?

I would appreciate for any help please. As of now my code selects single item from the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your listbox supports multiple select then the following code will select multiple values.

```
SelectElement Select = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlCUcardNo")));
Select.SelectByIndex(2);
Select.SelectByIndex(3);
Select.SelectByIndex(4);
```

This will select the items indexed at 2, 3, 4 and make sure you have items more than 4.
You can check the listbox is multi select by the following code.

```
SelectElement Select = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlCUcardNo")));
if(Select.IsMutiple)
  console.log("list box is multi select");
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to fire select commands on multiple elements one by one that’s it.

```
SelectElement element= new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id(element_ID)));
element.SelectByIndex(index);
element.SelectByIndex(index);

// Or can be used as
element.SelectByText(text);
element.SelectByText(text);

// Or can be used as
element.SelectByValue(value);
element.SelectByValue(value);
```